# Difference between element.setAttribute and element.style.setProperty

Tags: javascript, css

Assuming there is one custom css variable that I want to change it's value dynamically using JavaScript. I found that using `element.style.["--my-custom-var"] = value` will not work because it's a custom variable. Then I found out we can actually add custom css property to an element using `element.setAttribute` and `element.style.setProperty`. My question is that what's the difference between these two approach, such as which approach will have better performance and which one is the better practce if I want to add custom property using JavaScript.

Example:

```js
// both code is able to add custom css rule to the inline style of an element
element.setAttribute('style','--my-custom-var: 10px;');
element.style.setProperty('--my-custom-var', '10px');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `style` attribute removes all the other inline style properties from the element.

Using `setProperty()` only replaces that one style.

Notice in the example below that the background color is lost in the first div.

```js
document.getElementById("setstyle").setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
document.getElementById("setprop").style.setProperty("color", "red");
```

```html
<div id="setstyle" style="background-color: yellow; color: blue;">Setting style</div>
<div id="setprop" style="background-color: yellow; color: blue;">Setting property</div>
```